# trouble starting shorewall on Linode

Tags: firewall, linode, shorewall

Im having trouble configuring shorewall on my linode instance.
just thought maybe you know of an issue, perhaps related to your Xen virtualization and running shorewall on it...

when attempting to start shorewall I get the following error:
"ERROR: UNTRACKED state requires Raw Table in your kernel and iptables"

any ideas would be appreciated 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the kernel should have `CONFIG_IP_NF_RAW` (and `CONFIG_IP6_NF_RAW` for IPv6) enabled, which provides support for the missing *"Raw Table"* mentioned in the error.

A link to an (unmaintained) page for kernel configuration options with Shorewall can be found here:

http://shorewall.net/kernel.htm

However, if you are unable to update the kernel, you may be able to work around the issue by editing the `shorewall.conf` (or `shorewall6.conf`) file, and changing the following line:

```
BLACKLIST="NEW,INVALID,UNTRACKED"
```

to:

```
BLACKLIST="NEW,INVALID"
```

This would, obviously, reduce some of the effectiveness of the firewall, hence ideally the kernel should be updated instead.